# Extract information from BLE device

Tags: ionic-framework, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon, ionic-native

currently I'm working on a BLE project based on Ionic (**@ionic-native/ble**). I've asked couple of questions before and finally managed to write an entry-level app. But now it's come to another problem, which is that I don't know how to work with the data provided by the device.

Okay so first, my code is based on this guy's work: ***(Thank you, Don, btw)***https://github.com/don/ionic-ble-examples/tree/master/connect

And here is the demo:
[image]

[image]

As you can see, I have a fully functional estimote beacon and I'm required to get the **minor, major, ID** from that beacon. The problem is that in the second image I can't see any attributes that are related to the three above and furthermore, I don't know what to do with the bunch of information I get after connecting. So my question is, what to do after connecting to a BLE device, and, can anyone suggest me some good, for-dummies documentation that I can read to understand the meaning of those creepy strings of data? All the ionic-ble-tutorials that I found are outdated and documents about BLE are extremely hard to understand.

Comment: As painful as it is, once you get beyond the basics you probably will have to look for documentation using native Android Java APIs and then translate them to the equivalents when using ionic_native/ble.  It's hard enough to find good examples using the native Android APIs.

Comment: Hi, actually I just found out another ionic-native for iBeacon. Been playing with it for few hours and keep getting this issue: **ionic cannot read property didRangeBeaconsInRegion**. This is so frustrated and I don't really know how to figure out the issue. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

`Characteristics` are what you want to interact with whenever you are trying to `read`, `write` or `subscribe` for data. Look at all the `characteristics` and their `properties`. If their `properties` have '`read`', read those properties and see what kinda information you get. I think the Don Coleman plugin responds back with an `ArrayBuffer`. To convert an `ArrayBuffer` into a readable array of bytes, do

```
[].slice.call(new Uint8Array(value))
```

See if the documentation of the device matches the response you got back from the read. Are you expecting certain kind of values? If you don't know what to look for, it would be very hard to tell what is the relevant information looking at the array of bytes.